# How do I interact with QML from C++ in QtQuick 2.0

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt5

Let’s say that we have a very simple QML file, like this one:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: '#000'

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hi all")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

The QML File is loaded with the QtQuick2ApplicationViewer helper class, like this:

```
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/MyApp/Login/Window.qml"));
viewer.showFullScreen();
```

How should I proceed, if for example I would like to change the Rectangle’s color to white, from C++. My guess was:

```
QQuickItem *window = viewer.rootObject();
window->setProperty("color", "#fff");
```

But all that does is the following compiler error:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QQuickItem'
forward declaration of 'struct QQuickItem'
```

Comment: Did you include QQuickItem?

Comment: @LucaCarlon :D Thanks a lot. Never could have thought of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then QQuickItem was forward declared somewhere in a header you included, but not fully qualified. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class) more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
QObject *rootObject = (QObject *)viewer.rootObject();
rootObject->setProperty("color", "red");
```