# identifier "xxx" is undefined, class pointer and struct

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, typedef

I am writing a small c++ - program containing a similar structure to the following:

```
class A {
   B * someObjects;
};

typedef A* APointer;

struct B{
   APointer a;
   int n;
}
```

Trying to compile this gives a "identifier is undefined" error since struct B is not known inside class A. Otherwise declaring struct B before class A should still give a similar error, since then B does not know APointer, or APointer does not know A. Is there any possibility to make class A and struct B being good friends?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of thousands and thousands of existing questions. Did you not _search_??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to forward declare `B` as the compiler has no idea what `B` is when it is used in `A`.  `B` is considered an [incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class) in `A` and you are allowed to have a pointer or reference to `B` in `A`.  You can change your code to:

```
struct B;

class A {
   B * someObjects;
};

typedef A* APointer;

struct B{
   APointer a;
   int n;
};
```

Comment: Be an angel and wack a semicolon in after the structure definition. Nice answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard the term [Forward Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)! Your compiler don't know about `B` yet. So give a declaration of `B` first.

```
struct B; // forward declaration 

class A {
   B * someObjects;
};
//... rest of the code
```