# When does an Incomplete Type error occur in C++

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

Can anyone tell me when does a c++ compiler throw an "incomplete type error"?

Note: I have intentionally left this question a little open ended so that I can debug my code myself.

Comment: A possibly cv-qualified type that is not defined or is void is an incomplete type. An object shall not be defined as an incomplete type. And no, this is not a good question format

Comment: See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class-which-has-a-member-of-the-same-type-of-the-class-itse

Comment: @PasserBy I got somebody who answered my question and helped me find out the error. He was more helpful that you. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: When debug code that compiled by clang++, I reproduced, and switch to g++.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This happens usually when the compiler has seen a forward declaration but no full definition of this type, while the type is being used somewhere. For example:

```
class A;

class B { A a; };
```

The second line will cause a compiler error and, depending on the compiler, will report an incomplete type (other compilers give you a different error, but the meaning is the same).

When you however just use a pointer to such a forward declaration no complain will come up, since the size of a pointer to a class is always known. Like this:

```
class A;
class B {
   A *a;
   std::shared_ptr<A> aPtr;
};
```

If you ask what could be wrong in a concrete application or library when this error comes up: that happens usually when a header is included which contains the forward declaration, but full definition hasn't been found yet. The solution is quite obvious: include also the header that gives you access to the full type. Sometimes you may also simply have no or the wrong namespace used for a type and need to correct that instead.

Comment: Actually in my case, it is coming from a PCL library header file <window.h>. Since it is a library file, there should not be any error in the file as such. There should be something else which is driving in this error.

Comment: does it happen when the header files are included in the project but library is not linked???

Comment: No, compilation and linking are 2 different steps. First the compiler has to create object code (and therefor needs to know all used types), then the linker links them all together into the final binaries.

Comment: Thanks. The edit was very useful. I included the file that contained full definition before including the header. That worked.

Comment: This also comes up when a class definition has a member whose type is itself (e.g., a binary tree `Node` class that contains a left/right `Node` pointer). Question: how is the size of a pointer to a class always known? Is it fixed size (32-bits on a 32-bit machine, 64 bit on a 64-bit machine)?

Comment: Is it fixed sized, per architecture. But please ask follow up questions as own ones in SO.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when we try to use a class/object or its methods and they have not been defined yet. For example

```
class A;
class B {
    class A obj;
}
```

or

```
class A;
class B {
    class A *obj;
    B() {   
           obj->some_method();
        }
```

To resolve this, A has to be defined first or its total declaration has to given(best practice is to do it in a header file) and all methods of both the classes should be defined later(best practice is to do it in another file).

```
class A {
    //definition
}
class B {
class A obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you use forward declaration with `std::unique_ptr` (for example, to implement PIMPL idiom) in your class with a default destructor, which leads to such issue.

It is good explained here: [Forward declaration with unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414652/forward-declaration-with-unique-ptr)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to poor knowledge of templates. I declared a class between a template definition and the function which was associated with that template.

```
template<typename T>
class
{
  foo a;
  foo b;
};
function(T a,int b)
{

 . . . . .

}
```

And this created issues as the template definition is associated with the class, in this case, an error comes in the parameter list of the function that `T is not defined` and also that `incomplete type is not allowed`. If you have to use a template for multiple entities, then you have to reuse this statement before that entities' definition:

```
template<typename T>
```