# How to call a class recursively in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, fibonacci-heap

Hello this is the code:

```
template <class T> class FibonacciHeap{
public:
    class Entry{
        public:
            // Returns the element represented by this heap entry.
            T getValue(){
                return mElem;
            }

            // Sets the element associated with this heap entry.
            void setValue(T value){
                    mElem = value;
            }

            // Returns the priority of this element.
            double getPriority(){
                return mPriority;
            }

        private:
            int mDegree = 0;                // Number of children
            bool mIsMarked = false;         // Whether the node is marked

            Entry mNext;                    // Next element in the list
            Entry mPrev;                    // Previous element in the list

            Entry mChild;                   // Child node, if any
            Entry mParent;                  // Parent node, if any
            T mElem;                        // Element being stored here
            double mPriority;               // Its priority

            //Constructs a new Entry that holds the given element with the indicated priority.
            Entry(T elem, double priority){
                mNext = mPrev = this;
                mElem = elem;
                mPriority = priority;
            }
    };
    ...
```

In the Class "Entry" I want to call Entry recursively, so I can use:

```
    First_entry.mPrev.mNext
```

I know this works in Java, but when I compile this in c++, I get:

```
    error: 'FibonacciHeap<T>::Entry::mNext' has incomplete type
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or work around this?

Comment: Just a note: this is not recursion.

Comment: `Entry mNext;`, `Entry mPrev;`, etc You 're missing something here. Listen to the compiler.

Comment: In C++, most lists use pointers to nodes or `Entry`.  Java doesn't have pointers.

Comment: @m0skit0 what is it called?

Comment: @DimChtz what am I missing, I don't see?

Comment: @Chiray it's called chaining but that's not your problem here.

Comment: Related ( maybe duplicate ) : [“Incomplete type” in class which has a member of the same type of the class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class-which-has-a-member-of-the-same-type-of-the-class-itse)

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun yes, that solved it, thank you

Comment: A class pointing to itself has no special naming that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the variable names and initializers here, I'm assuming you're adapting my [Java Fibonacci heap](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap) into C++. :-) If so, best of luck!

In Java, if you have a variable of type `Entry`, it acts like a C++ variable of type `Entry*` in that it's a pointer to another `Entry` object rather than an honest-to-goodness `Entry` object. As a result, in the definition of the `Entry` class, you should adjust the fields so that they're of type `Entry*` rather than `Entry`. Similarly, instead of using the `.` operator to select fields, you'll want to use the `->` operator. So

```
First_entry.mPrev.mNext
```

would be rewritten as

```
First_entry->mPrev->mNext
```

Don't forget to explicitly initialize the `Entry` pointers to `nullptr` - Java does this automatically, which is why there are no initializers in the Java version. However, C++ gives uninitialized pointers garbage values, so make sure to give `mChild` and `mParent` an explicit `nullptr` value.

Comment: Well yes, I am trying to adapt it into C++. Thank you for you help!