# Does using an incomplete type within its own definition require a diagnostic?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, incomplete-type

This is a language-lawyer follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class-which-has-a-member-of-the-same-type-of-the-class-itse) question, where all the answers agree that the following is *not allowed*:

```
struct A { A a; };
```

There are several instances where incomplete types *can* be used, within the type definition itself, e.g.

```
struct A { A *a; };
struct A { A &a; };
struct A { std::unique_ptr<A> a; };
struct A { std::vector<A> a; };     // since c++17
```

etc.

My question is, are compilers required to diagnose programs that use incomplete types in a way that is not allowed? i.e. is it ill-formed? Or do these programs have UB? Or something else?

My feeling is that certain cases are just UB, like the `vector` example, which compilers don't usually diagnose, even though it was only legalized in c++17.

To clarify, I'm only asking about using incomplete types within the definition of the type itself, like in the examples shown.

Comment: I think this is too broad -- there are dozens of places where incomplete types can be used; sometimes it is well-defined, sometimes ill-formed and sometimes UB/NDR

Comment: @M.M edited the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the exact rule. Violations of most rules related to incomplete class types in the core language section of the Standard must be diagnosed. Uses as a template argument to a Standard Library template are undefined behavior unless otherwise specified, which gives a bit more latitude to implementations.

These rules require diagnosis (since they are stated with "shall"):

[[basic.def]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def#5):

> In the definition of an object, the type of that object shall not be an incomplete type ([basic.types]), an abstract class type, or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

[[dcl.fct.def.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def#general-2):

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be a (possibly cv-qualified) class type that is incomplete or abstract within the function body unless the function is deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).

[[expr.ref]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ref#4) (concerning the type of the operand expression before a `.` operator):

> The class type shall be complete unless the class member access appears in the definition of that class. [ *Note:* If the class is incomplete, lookup in the complete class type is required to refer to the same declaration ([basic.scope.class]). — *end note* ]

Since the built-in meaning of the `->` operator is defined with `A->B` equivalent to `(*A).B`, this also applies to `->` operator expressions.

[[class.mem]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#15):

> The type of a non-static data member shall not be an incomplete type ([basic.types]), an abstract class type ([class.abstract]), or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof. [ *Note:* In particular, a class C cannot contain a non-static member of class C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C. — *end note* ]

[[class.derived]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.derived#2) (concerning the list of base classes for a class definition):

> A *class-or-decltype* shall denote a (possibly cv-qualified) class type that is not an incompletely defined class ([class.mem]); any cv-qualifiers are ignored.

There are more core language rules forbidding incomplete class types, but the above are the most commonly relevant ones. See also the non-normative list of contexts requiring a complete class in [[basic.def.odr]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#12.note-1).

I don't see a direct rule that a *qualified-id* `scope::name` is ill-formed if `scope` names an incomplete class type, but it just may be that the name lookup will certainly fail in that case, which is a diagnosable violation.

For the Standard Library, the overall prohibition on incomplete types as template arguments is [[res.on.functions]/(2.5)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.functions#2.5):

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, this document places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - ...
> - If an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

As noted, C++17 added specific permission to instantiate class `std::vector<T, Alloc>`, but none of its members, if `T` is incomplete and `Alloc` satisfies the "allocator completeness requirements" ([[vector.overview]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.overview#4))